# How to switch tabs in jTabbedPane by clicking a Button?

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I have two JTabbedPanes, JTabbedPane1 & 2 
How can I press button in JTabbedPane2 to show JTabbedPane1 ?

Here is the code for JTabbedPane:

```
public class TabbedPane extends JFrame {

    public TabbedPane() {


        setTitle("Tabbed Pane");  
        setSize(300,300); 

        JTabbedPane jtp = new JTabbedPane();

       getContentPane().add(jtp);

       JPanel1 jp1 = new JPanel1();//This will create the first tab

       JPanel jp2 = new JPanel2();//This will create the second tab

       //add panel .........

    //example usage
     public static void main (String []args){
        TabbedPane tab = new TabbedPane();
    }

}
```

here is class JPane1:

```
...    JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
       label1.setText("This is Tab 1");
       jp1.add(label1);
```

and class Jpane2 with button on int

JButton test = new JButton("Press");
   jp2.add(test);

```
ButtonHandler phandler = new ButtonHandler();
test.addActionListener(phandler);
setVisible(true);
```

}
 so problem is here in ActionListener of button on Jpanel2

```
class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener{
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
              // what i do now ? to call  jpanel 1 show ![alt text][1]
       }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If you make the tabbed pane accessible to ButtonHandler you can do this:

```
class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener{
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
              jtp.setSelectedIndex(0);
       }
}
```

You can do this by making jtp (ideally with a better name) a private attribute with a getter method or it can be passed in as a constructor argument to ButtonHandler.

Comment: great :D I just forgot about the index.

Answer (score 9):

You should use the method `JTabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(int index)` with the index of the tab you want.

Answer (score 3):

its very simple: use the code below:

```
JTabbedpane.setSelectedIndex();
```

what ever the name is of you J Panel replace it with the above JTabbedpane and for example you want to select the first tabs simply put 0 in bracket and if you want to select second tab then put 1 in bracket eg: my J tabbed pane is called jtabbedpanel and I want the first tab then the line will look as:

```
jtabbedpanel.setSelectedIndex(0);
```

hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Just like to add that your action listener has to be in the same class as your tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Just! With:

```
JTabbedPane.setSelectedComponnet(component);
```

Comment: **From review queue:** May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers).

Answer (score 0):

here is fixed and full code.
after 12 years.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;  
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TabbedPane extends JFrame {
    public TabbedPane() {
        JTabbedPane jtp = new JTabbedPane(); 
        JPanel jp1 = new JPanel();//This will create the first tab
        JPanel jp2 = new JPanel();//This will create the second tab
        setTitle("Tabbed Pane");  
        setSize(400,300); 
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
        label1.setText("This is Tab 1"); 
        jp1.add(label1);
        //jp2.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:/users/user/downloads/jav/s1/pic1.jpg")));        
        getContentPane().add(jtp);
        
        JButton nextButton = new JButton("Next"); jp1.add(nextButton);
        JButton prevButton = new JButton("Previous"); jp2.add(prevButton);
        //prev
        class ButtonHandlerPrev implements ActionListener{
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                int i = jtp.getSelectedIndex();
                jtp.setSelectedIndex(i-1);
            }
        }
        class ButtonHandlerNext implements ActionListener{
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                int i = jtp.getSelectedIndex();
                jtp.setSelectedIndex(i+1);
            }
        }
        jtp.addTab("first", jp1);
        jtp.addTab("second", jp2);
        ButtonHandlerPrev prevHandler = new ButtonHandlerPrev();
        ButtonHandlerNext nextHandler = new ButtonHandlerNext();
        prevButton.addActionListener(prevHandler);
        nextButton.addActionListener(nextHandler);
        setVisible(true);
    }
        //example usage
    public static void main (String []args){
        TabbedPane tab = new TabbedPane();
    }
}
```

just run **void main(String[] args)**