# How to change selected JtabbedPane in Action Listener

Tags: jtabbedpane

I would like to change selected JTabbedPane "Calculation" after click on the button responsible for calculation with Action Listener to TabbedPane "Results".

Comment: duplicate of [How to switch tabs in jTabbedPane by clicking a Button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157293/how-to-switch-tabs-in-jtabbedpane-by-clicking-a-button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener{
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
              jtp.setSelectedIndex(0);
       }
}
```

here `jtp` is the object of JTabbedPane.

Have a look in [JTabbedPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#setSelectedIndex%28int%29) for further details.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you can use .setSelectedIndex(index), or .setSelectedComponent(component). Try to read javadoc :)